# What are the criteria for a sql staying in the V$SQLAREA?

Tags: oracle-10g

I needed to pick up details from a SQL result but 5 minutes after running the SQL it was no longer under `v$sql` and `V$sqlarea`. What are the criteria for Oracle to keep the query in those views?

Answer (score 6):

`v$sql` and `v$sqlarea` are views into the SQL area in the library cache (which is part of the shared pool, in the SGA).

What you see in those views are parsed/"compiled" statements that are in the cache. When a new statement comes in, Oracle checks to see if it already has it in that cache. If it does, it re-uses that (called a soft parse). (See [SQL Sharing Criteria](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/memory.htm#34746).) 
If not, it has to do a full parse and find room in the cache to store it (hard parse). If there's no room left in the cache, older statements are aged out.

How long a statement stays in cache depends on the size of the cache and how your database is used. If you have "few" distinct queries and use bind variables everywhere, and a sufficiently large library cache, it should be mostly static after "warmup".
If you're not using binds at all and have many distinct queries, or simply have a very small library cache, it'll recycle very fast.

For more details, see [Configuring and Using the Shared Pool and Large Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/memory.htm#30971) in the *Memory Configuration and Use* section of the tuning guide, especially the *Library Cache Concepts* and following sections.

Comment: acidently unmarked your answer as correct on my ipad. Trying to market back but I can't.